# Book series with inter-dimensional species. Vampire species chases prey to Earth

Tags: story-identification, books

In the book, two inter-dimensional species come to Earth;

- The first one is running from the other and gives human soldiers animal traits through mystical rituals.
- The second is a vampiric species it is described to look kind of like the dementors from Harry Potter (but with teeth).

Comment: Can you possibly add in some more details such as when you read it, or some more of the plot you might remember? Twists and conclusions? Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if it'll help jog your memory

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be talking about the [*Vampire Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_Earth) series by E.E. Knight.

> The story begins in 2065 in a post-apocalyptic American setting. Forty-three years earlier, in 2022, an alien race known as the Kurians triggered a series of natural disasters (as well as artificial ones) that enabled them to gain control of the planet and subjugate humanity. A plague has reduced the world population to 25% of its pre-cataclysm level; nuclear explosions have created a mild form of nuclear winter, cooling the Earth, and smaller events everywhere have added to the chaos. In America, the New Madrid fault let go, destroying much of the Midwest. Major rivers such as the Mississippi have been unleashed.

The two races involved are the Kurians and the Lifeweavers:

> The Kurians are a branch of an alien race known as the Lifeweavers. They naturally have very long lives of thousands of years and have learned to increase their lifespan indefinitely by absorbing vital aura from other living beings. This was discovered from the remnants of a civilization known as the Pre-Entities. After a civil war with the other Lifeweavers, the Kurians launched a large scale invasion of earth with an engineered virus known as "ravies" and triggering several natural disasters during a time of economic breakdown known as the New Depression. National governments quickly collapsed and the Kurians set up a new form of government, similar to feudalism, with Kurian lords controlling specific areas and maintaining their status quo through fear and intimidation. Though they have some interest in culture, their main goals are survival and power. Often they are compared to drug addicts, never looking much further than the next "fix" of vital aura from their human cattle. This of course belies their tenacity and power wielded through their Reapers.

....

> The Kurians' cousin species, the Lifeweavers, developed a means of turning human beings into weapons. These Hunters are divided into three castes: Wolf, Cat, and Bear. The Lifeweavers alter the bodies of the Hunters to grant them enhanced senses, reflexes and endurance.

The Kurians employ creatures named Reapers (or Harpies) that have more of a cloak-like appearance:

> The Kurians created these vampiric monsters that stalk the night, selecting victims for their insatiable masters. Each Reaper is an extension of its master, and when it pierces the heart of a victim with its long, flexible tongue to drain the unfortunate's blood, its connection to the Kurian controller transfers the vital aura. The Reapers are nigh-unstoppable; not only garbed in bullet-resistant cloaks but also possessing superhuman speed, agility, strength and resilience. Their blood is a powerful coagulant when exposed to air, sealing wounds almost instantly, and the bones of a Reaper are hard enough to deflect most bullets. The most terrifying aspect of the Reaper, however, is its ability to stalk prey by sensing out "lifesign", the energy given off by a living being. The greater the emotional distress of the target, the easier it is for the Reapers to find them.

This series I found by searching for *book vampire chases to earth*.

Comment: If this is the answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.